# What HTML/JS markup I have to remove from HTML to prevent XSS?

Tags: html, xss, sanitization

**I have to** render "User's" HTML as HTML.

"User" is an administrator, so it is kind of safe, but despite everything I'd want to prevent any xss-ish attack

I came with an idea like this:

```
while (html.Contains("script"))
{
    html = html.Replace("script", "");
}
```

Why `while`? because `scripscriptt` + replace `script` to `""` would still leave `script`

So, what are other key-words that have to be deleted?

`img`? due to loading data from other server

`iframe`?

`button`?

`href`?

**Over all I want to delete dangerous markup, but I do not want to delete safe things like `table, <b>, <div>` and the rest of text formatting / page style markups**

Comment: There are many and it might be a good idea to do it on the server side with a battle proof module. What is your backends language? E.g. https://github.com/punkave/sanitize-html

Comment: @CanK. Yea, I want to do on the server side - C#